# How to disable commented date in org mode html export

Tags: org-export, html

When you export an org file to html, a date will appear in the html source though commented.

Example, line 5 of https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqhn1.jpg .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate export option, which is `timestamp`. It's described at [Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings), but I always find that section ridiculously confusing, so here are some examples:

Either globally using a variable:

```
(setq org-export-with-timestamps nil)
```

or globally using a keyword:

```
#+options: timestamp:nil
* headline
one two three
```

or on an individual headline:

```
* headline
#+options: timestamp:nil
one two three
```

Comment: OP is asking about the autogenerated timestamp that gets inserted as an HTML comment which states the time the org file was exported. Your answer is talking about user-created timestamps in the org file, which is a different thing.

Answer (score 6):

To disable that globally, you can use `(setq org-export-time-stamp-file nil)`.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Hi @Veltas, thanks for this correction! let me update it.